# contract does not gets deploy to rinkeby via Infura

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, infura

I am trying to deploy my contract to Rinkeby network via Infura. But it actually does not get deploy to network when i run `node deploy.js` terminal does not spit out the address at which it is deployed. On screen i see it stuck. Please have a look at below screenshot. almost i kept it for a hour, but still same state.

[image: waiting]

Upon disconnecting the internet i get the below error, from this i can assume something was going on. there is no feedback system which shows the progress.

[image: err]

is there any way to know what is going wrong?

below is my deploy.js code

```
const HDWalletProvider = require('truffle-hdwallet-provider');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const compiledFactory = require('./build/CampaignFactory.json');

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
    secret_key,
    'https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<infura_key>'

);

const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    console.log('Deploying from account', accounts[0]);
    //console.log('Bytecode is 0x'+compiledFactory.bytecode);
    const result = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
        //.deploy({ data : '0x' + bytecode})
        .deploy({ data : '0x' + compiledFactory.bytecode})
        .send({gas : '1000000', from : accounts[0]}); 
   // console.log(interface);
   console.log('Contract deployed to ', result.options.address);
};

deploy();
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that `new` is somewhat ambiguous preceding the creation *and deployment* of a contract instance. You could try adding parenthesis:

```
const result = await (new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface)))
    .deploy({ data : '0x' + compiledFactory.bytecode})
    .send({gas : '1000000', from : accounts[0]});
```

Or even more explicitly:

```
var instance = new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface));
const result = await instance
    .deploy({ data : '0x' + compiledFactory.bytecode})
    .send({gas : '1000000', from : accounts[0]});
```